# Starling is giving Unable to transcode Image Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I am working on a prototype in which I'm adding a texture to movieClip.
Here is my code :

```
[Embed(source = "/../assets/demo_img.png")]
protected var asset01:Class;

[Embed(source="/../assets/demo_img.xml",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
protected var data01:Class;
```

and my movieClip code is :

```
var myTexture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new asset01());
var atlas:TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(myTexture, XML(new data01()));
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(atlas.getTextures("demo_img_"), 10);
```

but it gives me error :

```
Error: exception during transcoding: Failed to grab pixels for image \..\PP143Starling\assets\demo_img.png
```

If anyone have any idea about it, please share.

Comment: If you plain instantiate `new asset01()` and `new data01()`, will it throw an error or not?

Comment: No, it is not throwing any error.

Comment: Check if the path in XML is actually valid. I see an extraneous `PP143Starling` in the path in error.

Comment: That path is also correct, actually i have 2 sprite sheets with their XML file. 1st has 15 frames means 15 nodes in XMl file, it is loaded prefectly in movieClip, but 2nd one have 180 frames (180 nodes in XML), it is throwing error, and both  the XML files are generated by flash CS6 (sprite sheet generator), so it should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and the weird part was it started coming without any change in the code. Initially i faced an issue with windows memory and then eclipse memory and then this error surfaced:
exception during transcoding failed to grab pixels for image 
Embed was also not recognized by compiler anymore.

The fix is very simple. I just cleaned my project in eclipse and the error was cleared.